# Story ID: Collection of short stories about fantasy and possibly mythological beings and places?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, childrens-novel

I read a collection of short stories as an elementary school student in Canada around 2008 to 2010. This is a book.

I believe that there was a story associated with each letter of the alphabet from A to I. I believe the title of the collection contained the word "Indigo" in reference to the last story in the collection.

I remember there being colour illustrations, as well as plenty of text.

When closed, the book was approximately as big as a laptop (top-down). The book was hardcover and in good condition. The book was probably 2 to 3 centimetres thick.

Below are all of the stories I remember. I think each story had a different author. All of the stories had a "serious" tone to them. That is, they were not comedic, the characters experienced danger or difficult problems, and the solution used the fantasy environment. Perhaps these stories were based on folk tales.

1. A story about a monster in the north. I know that "A Promise is a Promise" by Michael Kusugak and Robert Munsch fits this description. However, I do not think that my collection contained "A Promise is a Promise". I couldn't find my collection on the Annick Press website (https://www.annickpress.com/Books/Picture-Books).
2. A coat made from the hide of many animals. Wearing the coat did something to the wearer,  maybe giving visions?
3. A desert that's really dangerous to be in because of the environment. One of the characters may have fallen ill because of the environment (it might be contact with sand, or caught in a sandstorm).
4. A story about polar night, and possibly ending a multi-year polar night.
5. The last story may have had the word "Indigo" in it, and something to do with an Isle or Island.